# Why might threads be considered "evil"?

Tags: multithreading, unix, thread-safety

I was reading the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf), and came upon this passage:

> [Threads are evil.](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf) Avoid them.

I don't quite understand the statement "Thread are evil". If that is true, then what is the alternative?

My superficial understanding of threads is:

- Threads make concurrence happen. Otherwise, the CPU horsepower will be wasted, waiting for (e.g.) slow I/O.
- But the bad thing is that you must synchronize your logic to avoid contention and you have to protect shared resources.

**Note:** As I am not familiar with threads on Windows, I hope the discussion will be limited to Linux/Unix threads.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the pdf? ;)

Comment: Voted to close as "not a real question" because the question links to the answer.

Comment: The original question, before it was edited, did not contain the phrase "My superficial understanding of threads is:" but was rather like: "My superficial understanding of *the article* is:"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When people say that "threads are evil", the usually do so in the context of saying "processes are good". Threads implicitly share all application state and handles (and thread locals are opt-in). This means that there are plenty of opportunities to forget to synchronize (or not even understand that you need to synchronize!) while accessing that shared data.

Processes have separate memory space, and any communication between them is explicit. Furthermore, primitives used for interprocess communication are often such that you don't need to synchronize at all (e.g. pipes). And you can still share state directly if you need to, using shared memory, but that is also explicit in every given instance. So there are fewer opportunities to make mistakes, and the intent of the code is more explicit.

Comment: The paper isn't really talking about processes specifically as the alternative

Comment: +1 - An interesting point are Erlang's threads which, since the language is purely functional and prohibits side-effects, work like processes and share data through message passing.

Answer (score 13):

Simple answer the way I understand it...

Most threading models use "shared state concurrency," which means that two execution processes can share the same memory at the same time.  If one thread doesn't know what the other is doing, it can modify the data in a way that the other thread doesn't expect.  This causes bugs.

Threads are "evil" because you need to wrap your mind around `n` threads all working on the same memory at the same time, and all of the fun things that go with it (deadlocks, racing conditions, etc).

You might read up about the Clojure (immutable data structures) and Erlang (message passsing) concurrency models for alternative ideas on how to achieve similar ends.

Answer (score 13):

What makes threads "evil" is that once you introduce more than one stream of execution into your program, you can no longer count on your program to behave in a deterministic manner.

That is to say:  Given the same set of inputs, a single-threaded program will (in most cases) always do the same thing.

A multi-threaded program, given the same set of inputs, may well do something different every time it is run, unless it is very carefully controlled.  That is because the order in which the different threads run different bits of code is determined by the OS's thread scheduler combined with a system timer, and this introduces a good deal of "randomness" into what the program does when it runs.

The upshot is:  debugging a multi-threaded program can be much harder than debugging a single-threaded program, because if you don't know what you are doing it can be very easy to end up with a race condition or deadlock bug that only appears (seemingly) at random once or twice a month.  The program will look fine to your QA department (since they don't have a month to run it) but once it's out in the field, you'll be hearing from customers that the program crashed, and nobody can reproduce the crash.... bleah.

To sum up, threads aren't really "evil", but they are strong juju and should not be used unless (a) you really need them and (b) you know what you are getting yourself into.  If you do use them, use them as sparingly as possible, and try to make their behavior as stupid-simple as you possibly can.  Especially with multithreading, if anything can go wrong, it (sooner or later) will.

Answer (score 9):

I would interpret it another way. It's not that *threads* are evil, it's that **side-effects** are evil in a multithreaded context (which is a lot less catchy to say).

A side effect in this context is something that affects state shared by more than one thread, be it global or just shared. I recently wrote a [review of Spring Batch](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/07/spring-batch-or-how-not-to-design-api.html) and one of the code snippets used is:

```
private static Map<Long, JobExecution> executionsById = TransactionAwareProxyFactory.createTransactionalMap();
private static long currentId = 0;

public void saveJobExecution(JobExecution jobExecution) {
  Assert.isTrue(jobExecution.getId() == null);
  Long newId = currentId++;
  jobExecution.setId(newId);
  jobExecution.incrementVersion();
  executionsById.put(newId, copy(jobExecution));
}
```

Now there are at least *three* serious threading issues in less than 10 lines of code here. An example of a side effect in this context would be updating the currentId static variable.

Functional programming (Haskell, Scheme, Ocaml, Lisp, others) tend to espouse "pure" functions. A pure function is one with no side effects. Many imperative languages (eg Java, C#) also encourage the use of immutable objects (an immutable object is one whose state cannot change once created).

The reason for (or at least the effect of) both of these things is largely the same: they make multithreaded code **much** easier. A pure function by definition is threadsafe. An immutable object by definition is threadsafe.

The advantage processes have is that there is less shared state (generally). In traditional UNIX C programming, doing a fork() to create a new process would result in shared process state and this was used as a means of IPC (inter-process communication) but generally that state is replaced (with exec()) with something else.

But threads are *much* cheaper to create and destroy and they take less system resources (in fact, the operating itself may have no concept of threads yet you can still create multithreaded programs). These are called **green threads**.

Comment: On Linux threads are not much cheaper than different processes running the same executable and share most of the data (COW). Linux does not really make a difference between treads and processes, except the PID is the same for different threads.

Answer (score 6):

The paper you linked to seems to explain itself very well. Did you read it?

Keep in mind that a thread can refer to the programming-language construct (as in most procedural or OOP languages, you create a thread manually, and tell it to executed a function), or they can refer to the hardware construct (Each CPU core executes one thread at a time).

The hardware-level thread is obviously unavoidable, it's just how the CPU works. But the CPU doesn't care how the concurrency is expressed in your source code. It doesn't have to be by a "beginthread" function call, for example. The OS and the CPU just have to be told which instruction threads should be executed.

His point is that if we used better languages than C or Java with a programming model designed for concurrency, we could get concurrency basically for free. If we'd used a message-passing language, or a functional one with no side-effects, the compiler would be able to parallelize our code for us. And it would work.

Comment: There's no such thing as a free lunch. The compiler writers have to do the same things that you would do to enable concurrency. They may do a better job; they may not.

Answer (score 5):

Threads aren't any more "evil" than hammers or screwdrivers or any other tools; they just require skill to utilize. The solution isn't to avoid them; it's to educate yourself and up your skill set.

Comment: Agreed. It sounds to me like the author simply doesn't know how to use threads correctly. Ignorance doesn't discredit the value of threads. Besides, I didn't see a clear alternative presented in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a lot of threads without constraint is indeed evil.. using a pooling mechanisme (threadpool) will mitigate this problem.

Another way threads are 'evil' is that most framework code is not designed to deal with multiple threads, so you have to manage your own locking mechanisme for those datastructures.

Threads are good, but you have to think about how and when you use them and remember to measure if there really is a performance benefit.

Answer (score 1):

A thread is a bit like a light weight process.  Think of it as an independent path of execution within an application.  The thread runs in the same memory space as the application and therefore has access to all the same resources, global objects and global variables.

The good thing about them: you can parallelise a program to improve performance.  Some examples, 1) In an image editing program a thread may run the filter processing independently of the GUI. 2) Some algorithms lend themselves to multiple threads.

Whats bad about them? if a program is poorly designed they can lead to deadlock issues where both threads are waiting on each other to access the same resource.  And secondly, program design can me more complex because of this.   Also, some class libraries don't support threading.  e.g. the c library function "strtok" is not "thread safe".  In other words, if two threads were to use it at the same time they would clobber each others results.  Fortunately, there are often thread safe alternatives... e.g. boost library.

Threads are not evil, they can be very useful indeed.

Under Linux/Unix, threading hasn't been well supported in the past although I believe Linux now has Posix thread support and other unices support threading now via libraries or natively. i.e. pthreads.

The most common alternative to threading under Linux/Unix platforms is fork.  Fork is simply a copy of a program including it's open file handles and global variables.  fork() returns 0 to the child process and the process id to the parent.  It's an older way of doing things under Linux/Unix but still well used.  Threads use less memory than fork and are quicker to start up.  Also, inter process communications is more work than simple threads.

Answer (score 1):

For any application that requires stable and secure execution for long periods of time without failure or maintenance, threads are always a tempting mistake. They invariably turn out to be more trouble than they are worth. They produce rapid results and prototypes that seem to be performing correctly but after a couple weeks or months running you discover that they have critical flaws.

As mentioned by another poster, once you use even a single thread in your program you have now opened a non-deterministic path of code execution that can produce an almost infinite number of conflicts in timing, memory sharing and race conditions. Most expressions of confidence in solving these problems are expressed by people who have learned the principles of multithreaded programming but have yet to experience the difficulties in solving them.

Threads are evil. Good programmers avoid them wherever humanly possible. The alternative of forking was offered here and it is often a good strategy for many applications. The notion of breaking your code down into separate execution processes which run with some form of loose coupling often turns out to be an excellent strategy on platforms that support it. Threads running together in a single program is not a solution. It is usually the creation of a fatal architectural flaw in your design that can only be truly remedied by rewriting the entire program.

The recent drift towards event oriented concurrency is an excellent development innovation. These kinds of programs usually prove to have great endurance after they are deployed.

I've never met a young engineer who didn't think threads were great. I've never met an older engineer who didn't shun them like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

Being an older engineer, I heartily agree with the [answer by Texas Arcane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36466194).

Threads are **very** evil because they cause bugs that are extremely difficult to solve. I have literally spent months solving sporadic race-conditions. One example caused trams to suddenly stop about once a month in the middle of the road and block traffic until towed away. Luckily I didn't create the bug, but I did get to spend 4 months full-time to solve it...

It's a tad late to add to this thread, but I would like to mention a very interesting alternative to threads: asynchronous programming with co-routines and event loops. This is being supported by more and more languages, and does not have the problem of race conditions like multi-threading has.

It can replace multi-threading in cases where it is used to wait on events from multiple sources, but not where calculations need to be performed in parallel on multiple CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple sense you can think of a thread as *another* instruction pointer in the current process. In other words it points the IP of another processor to some code in the same executable. So instead of having one instruction pointer moving through the code there are two or more IP's executing instructions *from the same executable and address space* simultaneously.

Remember the executable has it's own address space with data / stack etc... So now that two or more instructions are being executed simultaneously you can imagine what happens when more than one of the instructions wants to read/write to the same memory address at the same time.

The catch is that threads are operating within the *process* address space and are not afforded protection mechanisms from the processor that full blown *processes* are. (Forking a process on UNIX is standard practice and simply creates another process.)

Out of control threads can consume CPU cycles, chew up RAM, cause execeptions etc.. etc.. and the only way to stop them is to tell the OS process scheduler to forcibly terminate the thread by nullifying it's instruction pointer (i.e. stop executing).  If you forcibly tell a CPU to stop executing a sequence of instructions what happens to the resources that have been allocated or are being operated on by those instructions?  Are they left in a stable state?  Are they properly freed? etc...

So, yes, threads require more thought and responsibility than executing a process because of the shared resources.

Comment: This misses the problem with *multi* threading. You can "consume CPU cycles", "chew up RAM", "cause exceptions" with just the main process thread. The point about thread death not being managed by the OS is true in some environments that don't have gargage collection. Forcibly terminating misbehaving threads is a defective solution to concurrency issues. The solution is to correct the code after finding the cause of the issue -- Which is hard to do (being the point of the e-book).