# Thread Code Walkthrough, mechanics of Thread.Sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I'm having trouble understanding why this code is printing "Apple" instead of "Orange" after multiple runs. Can anyone help?

```
public class Fruit {

public static String fruit;

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        Thread t = new AppleThread();
        t.start();
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
        System.out.println("Thread generated an error.");
    }
    fruit = "Orange";
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println(fruit);
}

private static class AppleThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fruit= "Apple";
    }
}

}
```

The core of it for me has two questions:
1.) When referring to Thread.sleep(100) which thread is it referring to?

2.) We do t.start() in parallel to the main thread which assigns message = "orange". However, Apple is always what is printed out, why is this? "Apple" seems like it always gets the last assignment.

General clear up for this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.) When referring to Thread.sleep(100) which thread is it referring to?

The current thread which at the moment executes the piece of code containing the statement. In this case it is the main thread. It gives `t` a chance to do what it is supposed to do, otherwise the main thread would terminate an so the whole process without caring about `t` at all.

If you put `Thread.sleep` in the run method of `t`, then t goes to sleep.

> 2.) why always "Apple"?

What you're experiencing is the `main` thread creating a new thread `t` and calling its `start` method.

But this doesn't mean that now `t` actually runs and main does not. `main` continues its execution in parallel until it goes to sleep after the assignment `fruit = "Orange";`.

Maybe in the meantime `t` even gets a bit of cpu, but not enough to reach `fruit= "Apple";`. Only after `main` sleeps it can execute, so `fruit` as it happens always ends up as `Apple`, but not necessarily so.

Note, that this is the behavior at your machine/operating system/java application right now. Under different circumstances `t` might actually get enough cpu to fully execute before `main` reaches its assignment, then you'd be left with an Orange.

You actually have a [race condition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wettlaufsituation) built into your code, which lacks [synchronization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-block-synchronization-java/). What you seen now might *look* sequential. Start another few threads, use another operating system or cpu and something else might happen. It depends how the threads are [scheduled](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071214/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-3--thread-scheduling-and-wait-notify.html), which one draws first or just when. *Potentially* they're parallel, even to the degree that both write simultaneously to the variable. Which is [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278764/are-primitive-datatypes-thread-safe-in-java).

You ran your code a few times, always the same result. Run it 100.000 times, maybe always the same result, just except one time. Or just once a year or once per system life time. That's also the reason, why concurrency bugs or race conditions are so hard to track down, everybody avoids hand-crafted concurrent mutations and synchronization [like the plague](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191553/why-might-threads-be-considered-evil) and uses [immutable data](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-immutable-class-java/) and pre-mediated processing instead, like e.g. java parallel streams, or chooses to avoid to work in the field altogether and grow potatoes instead or whatever.

Btw. try to put `Thread.sleep(100);` before `fruit = "Orange";` and see, what is happening then. Or perhaps, instead of assigning just once per thread, call a separate method that repeatedly does something and yields, that might make it more transparent. It also creates a situation, where 2 threads run the same piece of code.

```
public static void printSome() {
        IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Thread %d says:%d", Thread.currentThread().getId(), i));
            Thread.yield();
        });
    }
```

Comment: When you say, "Only after main sleeps it can execute, so fruit is always Apple", it sounds very much that they are acting sequentially rather than in parallel. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, but only regarding the behavior you observed on your machine/cpu/jvm version at the current altitude/temperature/cpu clock rate/power grid voltage, with so many other threads/processes running etc., but change one or more of the factors and you may see something different ... I extended the answer a bit about that. Btw what happened with Thread.sleep(100); before fruit = "Orange";? Or with shorter sleep durations? You could also try a Thread.yield, which just gives up the currently assigned cpu slice of a thread, and continues on the next it gets.

Comment: When I put Thread.sleep() before fruit = "Orange", Orange shows up all the time now. Which supports your answer. Thread.sleep will allow the AppleThread to run, but then fruit = "Orange" has the last assignment before the print statement.

Comment: Also try the proposed `printSome()` method. Maybe you'll need `sleep` instead of `yield` to see something interesting, but let's see.